# Mongo shell is showing as "Connecting..." . But not Starting the Shell

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-shell

Im using `MongoDB` Community Server 4.0.

I installed properly as said in the `MongoDB` Documentation.

I have also set the path Environment variable for `MongoDB` `bin`.

The windows service for `MongoDB` is also running properly.

When I run MongoD with the following command

```
"C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin\mongod.exe" --auth --dbpath="c:\data\db" --bind_ip 127.0.0.1 --port 27017
```

the server starts perfectly displaying the log message as shown in the image

[image: the server starts perfectly displaying the log message as shown in the image]

Now when I start the mongo shell with the command

```
"C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin\mongo.exe"
```

I have also tried

```
mongo

mongo --port 27017

mongo --port 27017 --host localhost

mongo --port 27017 --host<machine name>
```

but it is just showing as

[image: connecting ... but not starting the shell as shown in the image]

Help me to solve this problem, please.

Comment: Are you able to see anything on your server command prompt after running mongo command? although all these parameters are optional you no need to provide even you no need to give the complete path for mongod or mongo as you already set as the environment variable.

Comment: No change in server..

Comment: its stays still saying ` waiting for connections on port 27017`...

Comment: What does your mongod server's log say? Do you see your connection attempt in there?

Comment: Nope . just "waiting for connection"